Authenticating Mobile Users on a Next.js Server with Supabase and RLS Policies
I am using the Supabase signup method to authenticate users in a mobile app. I want to make API requests to my Next.js server, where I also use the Supabase SDK to interact with the database. I have row-level security (RLS) policies in place that ensure only authenticated users can access specific data.
My goal is to:
Authenticate mobile users on the Next.js server.
Ensure the Supabase RLS policies are respected.
Use the same API endpoint for web clients as well.
Could you please guide me on how to achieve this setup? A working example would be very helpful.
